# How can I deny SELECT privelege to a single MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many tables that are r/w accessible to the webapp service account, as well as admin account.

One particular table called `foobarSettings` stores API key for a 3d party service I consume. I would like to make that table r/o for webapp account, and write-only for admin. So that webapp can read it, but can't write. And admin can update it, but can't read it back.

I found two solutions for this problem:

1. Grant UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT to webapp account for all tables *except* `foobarSettings` and grant SELECT to admin account to all tables *except* `foobarSettings`. And then remove privs for those users at global level, and at the database levels.
2. create a separate schema for `foobarSettings` table.

Both of those solutions have some maintenance overhead.

**Question:** is there an easier way to setup this configuration?

Comment: According to the MySQL mailing list you can not deny and action to a table that has been granted to the database. Looks like you might have to set table level access per table. Ref: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/171773

Comment: @Pheagey if the answer is "those are the only two options" - I will accept your answer if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL mailing list](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/171773) you can not deny and action to a table that has been granted to the database. Looks like you might have to set table level access per table.

From the [mailing list post](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/171773):

> "You can't revoke SELECT privilege from the table if you grant privileges on 
>   the database.
>   You can grant SELECT privilege on each table that you want to be visible to 
>   user instead."

Unfortunately this seems to be the only way atm.